# Burninate and blacklist [advice]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-blacklist

Every question is about advice: it'd be akin to tagging every question with [help](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/help) or [this-is-a-question-i-assure-you](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/this-is-a-question-i-assure-you). I would speculate the vast majority of questions tagged [advice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advice) are there because of misuse of the tag box (e.g. typing "career advice" instead of "career-advice").

So can we kill [advice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advice) with fire?

---

A year later the [tag is still here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advice?page=1&sort=newest&pagesize=50) and is still a fan favourite (100+ questions). Can we please burninate and blacklist it asap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Burninated and blacklisted.

Please [care for the orphans](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged).

Comment: Thanks, re-tagging the orphans now.

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like a fine plan to me.

The tag probably started out as "career advice" (i.e. without the hyphen) but it seems to have taken on a life of its own.

Comment: It should be a fire plan. `:-)`